# There's always more

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

In the traditional view of [my developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/120917?view=Cv), I see that there is "1 more" SE account I can check:

[image: One more]

But when I click it, then two new accounts appear:

[image: Two more]

And apparently, there's still one more. But when clicking it, unfortunately it looks like I don't have any more proper accounts, and it just goes back to the original state:

[image: One more]

Sorry for the lack of freehand circles, I'm on an OSX 10.11.6 (using Chrome 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit)).

Comment: Thanks for no freehand circles.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing...

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue! We're working through a list of bugs right now and I'll let you know once its fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! We have fixed this bug and it should be live with our next production build.

Comment: Works fine, cheers!